# Set alternate mode for stm32 rust HAL

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32f4, rust-embedded

I want to set alternate mode for AP10 of stm32f411 by rust HAl. My code looks like this:

```
let rx_pin = gpioa.pa10.into_alternate();
```

But it has multiple impl:

```
    = note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `stm32f4xx_hal::gpio::Pin<'A', 10>: gpio::marker::IntoAf<_>` found in the `stm32f4xx_hal` crate:
        - impl<MODE> gpio::marker::IntoAf<10> for stm32f4xx_hal::gpio::Pin<'A', 10, MODE>;
        - impl<MODE> gpio::marker::IntoAf<1> for stm32f4xx_hal::gpio::Pin<'A', 10, MODE>;
        - impl<MODE> gpio::marker::IntoAf<6> for stm32f4xx_hal::gpio::Pin<'A', 10, MODE>;
        - impl<MODE> gpio::marker::IntoAf<7> for stm32f4xx_hal::gpio::Pin<'A', 10, MODE>;
```

How can I fix this compile error?

Comment: Please post the full error, not part of it, and reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixex by specifying a value for generic

```
let rx_pin = gpioa.pa10.into_alternate::<7>();
```

Because the prototype of the method of into_alternate looks like this:

```
pub fn into_alternate<const A: u8>(self) -> Pin<P, N, Alternate<A, PushPull>>
```

And I need the alternate mode 7 for the pin.

This question sounds silly, but hope it will help someone still a absolute newbie crustacean (like me) in the future.